# trying to create a asp.net mvc viewpage w/o codebehind page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a view page in my asp.net-mvc app. For this, I have a strongly typed view, and I have also ovverriden the MVCPage class also.

For some reason when I load the page it says it can't load the type:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
Line 2:  Inherits="Blah.MyViewPage<Blah.ViewDataForBLahPage>" %>

public class MyViewPage<TViewData> : ViewPage<TViewData> where TViewData : class 

public class ViewDataForBlahPage : MyViewData
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [mvc no codebehind strongly typed viewdata headers not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615044/mvc-no-codebehind-strongly-typed-viewdata-headers-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is quite confusing to me so I'm not sure what's wrong.  But this is how I make mine to work (i.e. page without code-behind):

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyCustomViewModel>" %>
```

Replace `MyCustomViewModel` with your own view model class since you mentioned your view is a strongly-type view.

If it still doesn't work, might be posting more detailed code & reported error may make it easier for people to help...

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit

```
System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Blah.ViewDataForBLahPage>
```

Comment: If you follow his class hierarchy, he is doing just that.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen to me before, if I recall it happened when upgrading a site from a beta version of MVC.  The fix for me was to create a new MVC project and add re-add everything to it.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the namespace declaration for the class?

ETA: have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841311/asp-net-mvc-could-not-load-type-when-executing) thread? Could it be the same error?

Answer (score 0):

Check your web.config file, particularly the `<pages/>` section.  You may need to add the MYBlah.Core namespace to the namespace list.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because your class is non-generic, but you reference it as a generic class here:

```
 Inherits="MYBlah.Core.MyViewPage<MyBlah.Core.ViewDataForUser>"
```

For .NET, a generic class `MyViewPage` is different than `MyViewPage<T>`.

Comment: In that case... since the type couldn't be loaded, there might be a TypeLoadException involved. You could attach a debugger, set it to break at all exceptions and look at the details